# $('html').append() doesn't work on IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer-7

I need to insert a div in the DOM after the "html" tag. It works on all browser except in IE7.

After several test, it looks like i can't access to the html element with IE7.

For example :

```
$('html').append('mycontent'); //works with all browser except IE
```

Someone have an idea of how I can bypassing this IE7 limitation ?

Thank you.

ps: I test on IE9 in IE7 mode

Comment: Maybe this is being appended outside of your `body` tag - hence not being rendered?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<html>` is the root element. Aside from the DOCTYPE, there should be NO nodes outside it, and it should contain only TWO nodes, `<head>` and `<body>`. You should append new nodes to the `<body>`, maybe to the `<head>` if relevant, but never to the `<html>` itself.

Comment: +1 append to the `body` tag. But, of course, the `append` method would add content before the closing `html` tag and not 'outside it'.